# Custom sorting using a MySQL statement instead of simple field

Tags: views, search, 9

I'm using a view to list products from db index. I want to implement a custom sorting (my goal is to sort by current taxonomy term page, products having a specific node field field_MY_FIELD_NAME = CURRENT_TID, showing up first)

First using *hook_views_data_alter* I override the *sort* of an indexed field that I have chosen as a sort criteria inside the view

```
function MODULE_views_data_alter(array &$data) {
  $data['search_api_index_products_index']['category_tid']['sort']['id'] = 'current_category_first';
}
```

Next I created the corresponding class to alter the query sorting

```
namespace Drupal\MODULE\Plugin\views\sort;

use Drupal\search_api\Plugin\views\sort\SearchApiSort;

/**
 * Basic sort handler for product listing.
 *
 * @ViewsSort("current_category_first")
 */
Class CurrentCategoryFirst extends SearchApiSort{
  public function query(){
    $this->ensureMyTable();

    $formula = '-1 * FIELD(' . $this->tableAlias . '.' . $this->field . ',56' . ')';
    $this->query->addOrderBy(NULL, $formula, 'ASC','current_category_first');

  }
}
```

this mysql `$formula` is inspired from the module [views_list_sort](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_list_sort) witch is working fine with a simple view that do not retrieve from search API index (assuming that the term_id = 56, witch will be calculated later )

Unfotunately, This code do not list the view with the desired order, using ASC or DESC order change nothing (of course the tid=56 exists and is the current term page where i'm testing)

also using `sort` method instead of `addOrderBy` do not work, as it expect to have an existing field as a parameter and putting a formula throws "**Unknown field**" error

I tried also to separate the view into two views to use Union query but no luck as the query object of search api is not of type `SelectInterface`

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: question is what's wrong with this code, why it does not sort the view? any other idea also is welcome to achieve my goal described in beginning of the question.